How can I search a channel's parent and unthreaded messages while excluding replies?
Slack categorized messages as follows:

Unthreaded:
Has no replies.
Parent: Has replies.
Child: A reply.

How can I search through a Slack channel's unthreaded and  parent messages, while excluding any child messages (replies)?
 
Slack > Platform concepts > Messages

Before a message has any replies, we call it an unthreaded message.
Once a message has replies, it becomes a parent message.
Any child messages of that parent message are called threaded replies.

